# Swapping / exchanging two selections in Webstorm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea, string-manipulation, webstorm

Is there a way of swapping two selections under multiple carets like in `sublime-text` in the Jetbrains' editors like Webstorm.

The default shortcut in sublime text is `CTRL+T` for the `transpose` command.

Perhaps there is a plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not currently supported. Please vote for [IDEA-80498](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80498)